# S3 Query Exception file has an invalid version number and InvalidRange The requested range is not satisfiable

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am running a Python script that read a lot of parquet files from a S3 bucket and insert the dataframe into redshift. However, the errors "S3 Query Exception file has an invalid version number" and "InvalidRange The requested range is not satisfiable" frequently happen, I say "frequently" because it is not always that this occur but mostly of the executions.

For each insertion I commit the changes, until the read proccess end and then I close the cursor and the connection. This started when I updated my script, the old version read all files and insert to redshift. Now it read one file and insert the data. What may be causing this problem?